# Retrieve resource Image dynamicaly with Image FileName associate

Tags: c#, image, system.reflection

I have the following code that can retrieve the images from a folder in my project architecture:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
ResourceManager objResourceManager = new ResourceManager(assembly.GetName().Name + ".g", assembly);
ResourceSet objResourceSet = objResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);
List<ImageAndDescription> imageAndDescriptions = new List<ImageAndDescription>();

foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry entry in objResourceSet)
{
    string filePath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(entry.Key.ToString());
    if(filePath.StartsWith(folderPath.ToLower())
        imageAndDescriptions.Add(new ImageAndDescription(entry.Value, entry.Key.ToString()));
}
```

With this code I can retrieve the Resource image stream associated (entry.Value) but the name of that image (entry.Key) is in lower case and would like to retrieve the right one in order to have a relevant description for that image.

Could any one help pointing that out?

Thanks

Comment: how does the "right one" look like?

Comment: The rigth one is a text with the case sensitive. For instance some images are country name, one right name will be "United States.png" and for now I can only get "united states.png"